Expectation of correct ordering in blind ranking
Alice and Bob are playing a game where Bob will give Alice $4$ natural numbers, one by one, all less than $100$. Alice has to put them in an order. Alice's score will be the number of correct ordering between any two numbers. The rule of order is: the greater number will be on the left of the lesser. For example, a score of $33,56,57,89$ is 0, a score of $89,54,90,99$ is $1$. In the second example, Bob gave her the numbers in the following order: $54,89,90,99$. It is easy to show Alice can score at least $1$. What is the expectation of score, $E(s)$? Does Alice have any strategy to score more than $1$, and does Bob have his optimal strategy to restrict the score of Alice at $1$?
PS: I thought about this problem from a recent trend of blind ranking of footballers after following a course on expected value by Prof. Tom Leighton.

1/ Are Bob's numbers fixed beforehand (IE He can't change them based on what Alice does) $\quad$ 2/ Can you elaborate on how Alice scores at least 1?

Bob can give numbers to Alice according to  position where Alice puts her previous number. If bob give Alice any number not equal to 1 or 100 then she can put it in 2nd or 3rd empty space from left. As any way  among the rest three numbers at least one number will fall on the left or right of the 1st given number.  This will be a correct ordering and score will be at least 1.If bob gives her 1 or 100 at any move before the last number she can put it either of the extreme left or right. That will also guarantee  at least 1

Can you show that for the 3 number version, Bob can force Alice to score at most 1?

Bob can give 1st number as lets say 20 .Alice will put it in middle. Now Bob will give Alice rest 2 numbers both less than 20 or greater than 20 .This will make Alice to score 1 but not more say final sequence comes as 40 20 60.

Great! Apply a similar reasoning to  the 4-number version.

It could be helpful to test out a smaller case, which can provide some insights for how to approach the problem.

Lemma left to the reader: In the 3-number version of this game,

Alice can score at least 1.
Bob can force Alice to score at most 1.
Hence Alice always scores 1.


I encourage you to think about this.
If you're stuck, read OP's comments in the post, or modify the approaches for the 4-number version.

OP has shown in the comments that Alice can score at least 1.
We will show that Bob can force Alice to score at most 1, so Alice will always score exactly 1, and the expected score is 1.
4-number version:    Bob gives the first number of 50.

If Alice places it on the 1st (or 4th, take the reverse), Bob plays the 3-numbers game with 1-49, so Alice can score at most 1.
If Alice places it on the 2nd (or 3rd, take the reverse), Bob gives 40.

If Alices  places it on the 1st (scoring at least 1), Bob gives 30. Depending on whether Alice places it on the 3rd or 4th, Bob gives 25 or 35, scoring 1.

If Alice places it on the 3rd, Bob gives 45.
- If Alice places it on the 1st (scoring at least 1), Bob gives 35 to be placed in the 4th, scoring 1.
- If Alice places it on the 4th (scoring at least 1), Bob gives 60 to be placed in the 1st, scoring 1.

If Alice places it on the 4th, Bob gives 45.
- If Alice places it on the 1st (scoring at least 1), Bob gives 43 to be placed on the 3rd, scoring 1.
- If Alice places it on the 3rd, Bob gives 60 to be placed on the 1st, scoring 0.




